# Timer does not fire in a multi-thread form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a `System.Timers.Timer` timer in a form. Also I have a thread that reads from an RFID device (with function: `GetData()`). I want to limit the time of my thread with a timer, but the timer does not fire.

```
System.Threading.Thread GetData;
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
int reverseCounter=1000;

    public CardDragMaifareFrm()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 10;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
        GetData = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReadCardData));
        GetData.Start();
    }
   void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (reverseCounter > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("hey");
            reverseCounter -= 1;
        }
        else
        {// some actions for terminating GetData thread}
    }
```

but I don't see "hey" message... can anybody help me? thanx

Comment: *"does not work"* - what doesn't work? Do you see `MessageBox` ? It's unclear what is `reverseCounter` so we can't check possible logical mistakes. `reverseCounter -= reverseCounter` is equal to `reverseCounter = 0`.

Comment: A note not directly related to your problem: `timer.Enabled = true` and `timer.Start()` do the same thing - you should remove one or the other.

Comment: @ Reza i correct `reverseCounter` but timer hase not fire yet

Comment: @Sinatr, sorry because of unclear question. I mean the timer does not fire... regardless of any other part of code.. i corrected `reverseCounter` but it does not work yet

Comment: 10 ms isnt a very long timer... it does seem odd it wouldnt fire at all.

Comment: So `void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            MessageBox.Show("hey");
    }` doesn't show message either?

Comment: @weston no :( i also used a progressbar, but it does not work too... i think timer does not fire at all

Comment: And if you remove the thread `.Start`?

Comment: [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx): "If you use the System.Timers.Timer class with a user interface element, such as a form or control, without placing the timer on that user interface element, assign the form or control that contains the Timer to the `SynchronizingObject` property" (Although I'd usually suggest just switching to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which is *designed* to interoperate correctly with UI right from the start)

Comment: @weston no change... disappointing:(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no any change occured when i use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.. have u any other suggestion?

Comment: So by process of elimination, it's nothing to do with the thread then.

Answer (score 0):

I used the first rule of computer engineering: Restart it, maybe it will work"... ;-)